# Gets.chomp() user input error in Ruby

Tags: ruby, user-input

So this is my code. It's pretty self-explanatory.

```
print "How old are you? "
age = gets.chomp()
print "How tall are you?"
height = gets.chomp()
print "How much do you weigh?"
weight = gets.chomp()
puts "So, you're #{age} old, #{height} tall and #{weight} heavy."
```

My code output is as follows.

```
$  C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe ex11.rb
11
11
11
How old are you? How tall are you?How much do you weigh?So, you're 11 old, 11 tall and 11 heavy.
```

It's probably a really simple error, but I would be grateful if you can point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that your question is: "All my prompts are printed all at once after all inputs. What's up with that?". I have an answer for you then :)

`print` doesn't add a newline to the string. And STDOUT doesn't flush until it's got a full line. Simple fix: replace `print` with `puts` (which does add newline char)

```
puts "How old are you? "
age = gets.chomp()
puts "How tall are you?"
height = gets.chomp()
puts "How much do you weigh?"
weight = gets.chomp()
puts "So, you're #{age} old, #{height} tall and #{weight} heavy."
```

Comment: Do you know any setting for *Notepad++*,as `TextMate` has ? Like if I write `2 + 3 # =>` and run the code, would get `2 + 3 # => 5`

Comment: @Priti: nope, i have no idea

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't quite seem to work. I understand why it has to be puts but I keep getting the same error in Cygwin. I have run the new code on an online IDE and it works there.

Comment: What error is that? Works for me. Probably it's something with your local env (Cygwin)

Comment: All my prompts are still printed after my inputs in Cygwin.

Comment: Did you forget to save the file?

Comment: Checked that. :) I saved it (multiple times). If it helps, I am running this in Cygwin. I installed Ruby from RubyInstaller.

Comment: Are you running wrong version of the file? Anyway, the problem is in your env, not the ruby code.