# Difference in behaviour between Cygwin and Command Prompt when running Ruby scripts

Tags: ruby, cygwin, gets, puts

I'm running [exercise 14](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex14.html) of Learn Ruby the Hard Way. If I run the script in cmd it works fine, but I've been using Cygwin because it's nicer. When I run it in cygwin using this command:

```
ruby ex14.rb Devon
```

I get the following output

```
test
one
two
Hi Devon, I'm the ex14.rb script.
I'd like to ask you a few questions.
Do you like me Devon?
> Where do you live Devon?
> What kind of computer do you have?
> Alright, so you said test about liking me.
You live in one.  Not sure where that is.
And you have a two computer.  Nice.
```

That is to say, the program starts and immediately runs the three `STDIN.gets.chomp()` commands, and once it gets through those it `puts` and `prints` everything at once.

Is there a way to fix this behaviour? I would obviously want to have the lines run in the order they are written. I was unsure what to google for this type of error - combinations of "cygwin", "ruby", "puts output delayed" and "gets out of order" returned nothing relevant. Those search terms seem to vague anyway.

What exactly is going on, and is there a solution?

Comment: WFM with the Cygwin ruby.  Are you trying to use a Windows ruby from the Cygwin prompt?

Comment: @Yaakov I have both tried the Windows-installed ruby, and reinstalled cygwin with all ruby modules. Both exhibited the same behaviour.

Comment: @Yaakov now I don't know for certain that when I ran the script the second time, it actually used the ruby module and not the win-ruby.

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/ruby ex14.rb Devon` from the Cygwin prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is all to do with the CR LF differences between dos and unix.
try this...

```
set -o igncr
```

before running your script.

Comment: This might help also...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320251/gets-chomp-user-input-error-in-ruby